# How to set a rect property with width and height bound to elements in XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a custom control with a "SafeDisplayArea" property. The SafeDisplayArea property tells the control what parts of the control are safe to show things on.

SafeDisplayArea is a Rect.

Setting the property in XAML like this works just fine.

```
<CustomControl SafeDisplayArea="0,0,100,200"/>
```

What I want to do is set the height and width of SafeDisplayArea to be the same as other elements in the page.

Something like:

```
<CustomControl SafeDisplayArea="0,0,{Binding Width, ElementName=TitleBar}, {Binding Height, ElementName=TitleBar}" />
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, the best option would probably be to use a `MultiBinding`, unfortunately this class is not available in WinRT...

Another option is to bind to `TitleBar` itself and use a converter to return a `Rect`.

```
<CustomControl SafeDisplayArea="{Binding ElementName=TitleBar, Converter={StaticResource elementToRectConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. We've all wanted to do this!

The converter solution is good for a OneTime binding, but the overhead of a Rect converter is nothing to play around with. Converters are expensive by themselves, and this would be a potentially costly operation if it happened in many places or very often.

The best thing to consider is that you cannot do this.

> Limitations to bindings are almost always the result of performance implications. If you consider the presence of StaticResource but the absence of DynamicResource you can see this clearly. StaticResources are almost identical to Mode=OneTime while Dynamic are almost like Mode=TwoWay bindings. In WinRT-XAML, these deltas with WPF are typically intended to enable faster interfaces. Just because YOU CAN bypass these performance precautions, doesn't mean it is a good idea.

Having said that, this is your app. You know what is best in the end. If this is a necessary requirement, the performance implication is something you can actively choose to accept. I think we all realize that.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a bindable property for each width and height and set the appropriate rectangle properties in the setters?